# GMail Email Relay Message 404

Tags: email, gmail

I asked this question on Stack Over Flow and someone let me know that I should probably post it here.  I am using Elastic Email's API to send email from my website and I am getting errors from GMail that I don't understand.  Here is my post:

I am getting the following message returned from GMail "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

The software I'm using is retrying the email so I'm wondering what 404 (not found) means? As my assumption is that it couldn't find the mailbox however I have received these bounced email messages from Gmail as well, so i'm confused:

"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for"

Thanks